# Unity doesn't recognize microphone, but Windows does

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, microphone

So I got a little problem, I'm trying to get a recording using my microphone in Unity. The mic is plugged-in and is recognized by Windows. Recordings with Audacity are working too.
In Unity however the microphone is not recognized.

```
    foreach (string device in Microphone.devices)
    {
        print("Name: " + device);
    }
```

This code gives nothing back, and this isn't giving me any errors either:

```
    yield return Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone);
    if (!Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone))
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Microphone using not authorized");
    }
```

This as a result gives me an IndexOutOfRangeException:

```
Microphone.Start(Microphone.devices[0], false, 10, 16000);
```

Did I forget anything? I tried it with 2 different microphones, but both are not recognized within Unity, even though Windows can see them.

Comment: what kind of microphone? Any brand/versions? Are it USB microphones, does it use audio jack?

Comment: There are no brands to be found on the devices, so I do not know that.  It's a desktop microphone and a singing microphone. One uses a big jack, the other a small one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the issue. Probably driver related. I removed the Realtek HD Audio software from my pc, and everything worked.